# Should it be "100% donations policy" or "100% donation policy"?

Tags: grammar

Some charities have a "100% donations policy" or "100% donation policy" - e.g. "We abide by a 100% donations policy" - by which they mean that 100% of each donation donated to the charity will go to the charitable cause(s) (and not a penny will be deducted for administration purposes).

The question is: should it be **donations** (as a plural) or **donation** (in the singular) in the above *policy*? Or are the two interchangeable?

I'm guessing what they're really saying is **We abide by a "100% of your donation*s*" policy**, in which case both (plural and singular forms) would make sense?

Or is the *policy* just worded badly?

<sup><sup>Or am I just reading too much into this?</sup></sup>

Comment: I think you're reading too much into this.  ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grammatically I'd say both are okay, but I'd prefer '*100% donation policy*'.

You're describing your policy on handling donations, or your *donation policy*, and your organisation's policy is one which is commonly referred to as the '*100% policy*' or '[*100% model*](http://www.charitywater.org/100percent/)'. In other words, you're really saying '*We abide by a "100%" donation policy*'. Although I wouldn't be surprised to find both forms in use.

Comment: Thanks for the insight and especially the [100% model](http://www.charitywater.org/100percent/) link.